# Grails Service Calls From TagLib Overhead

Tags: grails, service, taglib, overhead, method-call

I have a really simple taglib and service:

```
class TestTagLib {
    FooService fooService

    static namespace = "bar"

    def test = {
        out << "text"
    }
}

class FooService {
    //This is an empty method that does absolutely nothing
    void foo() { }
}
```

If I repeat this taglib 20 times on a page, it executes instantly.  But now if call that service:

```
...

fooService.foo()
out << "test"

...
```

Suddenly those 20 taglibs cause the page to take 2 seconds to load. This doesn't seem right that the overhead of a service call would be so high...or is it? How would I even go about debugging this?

Comment: i guess it depends on what you're doing in foo() :-)

Comment: As I put in the example, it's doing literally nothing. It's an empty method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service methods are by default transactional. So, for every call of `fooService.foo()` you are getting the overhead of a complete database transaction creation and commit.

Comment: In that case, how would you make a method transactionally read-only or not transactional at all?

Comment: I ended up putting static transactional = false on services with no inserts/deletes, and if I needed it at the method level I used @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER) (set propagation to whatever you need, javadoc here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html).  This works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I tend to use the annotations as much as possible. It also allows things like marking certain methods as read-only. Then hibernate can make more intelligent optimization decisions.